# Watts and Strogatz graphs in Python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I need to generate a random graph with Watts and Strogatz. I am looking for an identical format to my real data. I have to save it in csv or txt file. It is more like [Small World Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network)
As per what i have read in the about Watts and Strogatz is it is undirected graph with no weights. But i need to generate undirected graph with weight.

Real data format

```
Node  Node weight = time in seconds
  453  645    343
  453  645    533
  645  8090   349
  645  453    3563
  564  645    3533
  564  453    345
  8090 453    563
  8090 645    4525
  564  8090   3533
```

The Degree is 1 and the two node pairs are connected for certain time and that is given in seconds. what is the best way to generate the graph data with Seed (0 to 4) in time (1 to 5), i.e. Seed0_time1 and so on till Seed4_time5. Five instances.

I understand it might be too broad but it would be great if someone can point me toward the right direction and with some code in support. I did look for help here i see hardly any posts that have been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/)? They have a bunch of these small world algorithms, including [Watts-Strogatz](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.watts_strogatz_graph.html#networkx.generators.random_graphs.watts_strogatz_graph), and they are fairly easy to use. **If you really want an undirected graph with no weights, have a look at the set of [Classic random graphs](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.classic) NetworkX can generate**. But if you have to go with Watts-Strogatz, below is sample code for using it with NetworkX. Most of the random graph generators return a `Graph` object, so [here's](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/functions.html) documentation about the methods available for the `Graph`.

```
import networkx as nx
watts_strogatz = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(200,2,0.15)
nx.nodes(watts_strogatz) # Prints out the nodes
```

Comment: How about representing the weight as the number of edges between two nodes? For example, two node pairs are connected for 343 seconds could be represented by having 343 edges between the nodes. Did I get it right?

Comment: The seconds is time those two nodes connected to each other that could be any number.

Comment: My understanding is that you have a specific dataset, which defines the nodes and their connections. In that case, would you really need to generate a random graph like Watts-Stogatz? Seems you need to represent your dataset using NetworkX. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes you are right but i do have to Watts Stogatz with a little modification